# get_field not works at foreach loop in php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am a beginner at php, i'm trying to get Gallery Images of every post in the loop to return it in Rest API

```
    $mylink = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    if (count($mylink) > 0){
        foreach ($mylink as $prj){
            $galleries = Array();
            $pid = $prj->id;
            $gs = get_field('gallery', $pid);
            if($gs == null){
                $gs = Array();
            }

            foreach ($gs as $g){
                $c = new stdclass();
                $c -> id = $g["ID"];
                $c -> url = $g["url"];
                $galleries [] = $c;
            }
            $prj -> PID = $pid;
            $prj -> GS = $gs;
            $prj -> gallery  = $galleries;
            $prj -> image = ''.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($prj->id) );
        }
        $results_array['msg'] = 'Success';
        $results_array['status'] = true;
        $results_array['result'] = $mylink;
        $results_array['current_time'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        return $results_array;
    }
```

I can get the Gallery Images of every single post in page but it doesn't show any thing in the Rest API

Comment: This is a wild guess, but have you checked that you are making the call to `get_field()` after init? See [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-custom-fields-get_field-intermittently-returning-false-after-acf-341-342-update) for more details.

Comment: can you explaine more please ? i sayed, i am beginner and don't underastand it .

Comment: When you add your own PHP code to WordPress, you need to be aware of the point of execution where your code gets executed. I would suggest that you read the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/), the section on Hooks explains it all. In addition, you might want to use some simple plugin tutorials that show the actions/filters in use.

Comment: i mean i should to include function.php file ?

Comment: In which hook (action) does the code above get called? Or is it in a hook at all? It must be in a hook that gets called after init.

Comment: there is php class 'helper.php' include it into other files to use it methods, the method i use named 'getProjects' it is all there is

Comment: Then my suggestion is (and I cannot promise this resolves your problem) that you follow the [guidelines](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-custom-fields-get_field-intermittently-returning-false-after-acf-341-342-update) given by the plugin author and "use wp_head or admin_head or any other actions here". It is just a couple of lines of PHP code.

Comment: i should to use add_action  in helper.php ? helper.php is not plugin file

Comment: Basically, hooks can be added anywhere in the code, not just in plugin files.